# openmpi libraries for c++

Tags: c++, mpi

I am using an ubuntu 10.04 system and I installed mpi libraries using

`sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev`

I am able to compile and run pure c-mpi code using the commands mpicc and mpirun but I am not able to compile cpp-mpi code using mpicc

Do I need to install any additional libraries to compile cpp code ?

Answer (score 2):

more googling gave me the answer

I had to use `mpicxx` to compile and run the code